# Run code before Pivot Table change via slicer

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am not even sure if this is possible.

So I have the below `Worksheet_Change` and `Worksheet Calculate` that will format my worksheet every time (Hide Rows & format Date if needed) I select a Pivot table Filter item in a Slicer I created. Now another function **I am hoping to add** is to have a 'Comments' column that is placed at the adjacent column beside and out of the Pivot Table area. These 'Comments' will be copied and pasted as Values to another sheet along with the data of the Pivot. Again, the Pivot table will only be copied and pasted as values too.

What would normally happen is that when a Filter item is selected in the Slicer, the Pivot table area's Number of Columns will change because the Value Fields are dynamic. So it may be one column on one Filter item, and eight Columns to another. This means I cannot place a "Comments" column beside the Pivot Table's last column at the right because it may end up over written by the new Filtered report. So yeah, before the overwriting happens, I hope to copy the Comments Columns first to another worksheet.

any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b1:p7")) Is Nothing Then




'Unhide all rows first

    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("A1:A1000").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

'Hide rows outside Pivot Table report area
    Range("A7").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True


    Range("A800").Select 'above project no.
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True


'format date
        If Range("G7") = "End dates Due" Then
        Range("G7").Select
        ActiveCell.Range("A1:A792").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Else
        Range("G7").Select
        ActiveCell.Range("A1:A792").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    End If






End If


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Me.Range("A802").Value = "" Then 'below project no.
        Me.Range("A796:A801").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'from proj manager to project no.
    Else
        Me.Range("A796:A801").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Me.Range("A823").Value = "" Then 'below project no.
        Me.Range("A817:A822").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Me.Range("A817:A822").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Me.Range("A802").Value = "" And _
                     Me.Range("A823").Value = "" Then
        Me.Range("A794:A822").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'from report no. to 2nd proj. no.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just place the `Comments` to the left of the PivotTable.

Comment: well I am hoping to make it more functional as in a fill out table that people would normally add comments on the right of the Data that they are referring to

Comment: Instead of copying the comments before the PivotTable is updated copy them after they are entered. That way the comments will end up in their destination earlier and the information will concurrent.

Comment: Use the `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` event to create the range for the comments, and the `Worksheet_Change` event to validate and move the comments to their destination.